# Refine Search and return List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a function to sort and return a list.

```
return Snacks;
```

Before the list is returned I would like to perform an additional select. Which only selects the record with a certain date eg. 25th/March/2013.
So as it stands the list returns 5 records. By narrowing it to only selecting 25Th March 2013. I will get the only 3 records I need.

The column in the record that I would like to use to refine the search is 'ActivityDate' SO how do I narrow this down?

Is it something like

```
    Snacks.SelectMany(//add date);
```

or

```
    Snacks.Select(where activityDate = ??);
    return Snacks;
```

P.S I realise there are other ways to do this and I should probably do it in the intial search in the function but I need to do it just before the list is returned. SO any advice would be appreciated thank you

**Edit**
Thanks for the replies everyone but I am not trying to add any more records to the list. I Already have 5 records in the list which I now what to bring down to 3. By doing this I would like to only select the records in the list where a date == filterDate.

When I tried your attempts at .ToList they all added the 3 record I needed but the other 2 are already there from a previous search.

Comment: Do the dates in the records include times? Can we just deal with the date without time? Or do we need to keep only records with datetime before midnight on March 25?

Comment: time is included in the dates but they are all 00:00:00

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: In response to juharr`s comment and to promote having great content for SO, let me update my answer.

A collection can be filtered using the `where` method. `Where` method is an extension method that lives in `System.Linq` namespace so make sure you include that in the code file where you put the suggested code below (e.g. do a `using System.Linq;`).

You can assign the filtered collection to a variable or return it directly.

```
var filteredSnacks = Snacks.Where(x=>x.ActivityDate == filterDate).ToList();
return filteredSnacks;
// or simple do a 
return Snacks.Where(x=>x.ActivityDate == filterDate).ToList();
```

Comment: The where method does NOT add elements to your collection but rather take them out. So I'm not sure what you meant by your updated question.

Comment: This line of code is misleading.  You should either be assigning it to a variable (possibly `Snacks`) or returning it.  Otherwise it gives the impression that it will filter the original list in place, which it does not.

Comment: Why would it be misleading when the OP knows what to do with `Snacks`? The OP can either assign it to a variable first then return that variable to a view, another calling method or whatever, or return it directly.

Answer (score 3):

Is it not something as simple as:

```
return Snacks.Where(s => s.ActivityDate == DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

(for example)?

Comment: `Where` isn't going to add anything to your current collection, so someone's misunderstood something (i.e us misunderstanding what you require or you misunderstanding the solution). Could you post what you code you now have?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Where`:

```
var snacks = Snacks.Where(s => s.ActivityDate == "25/03/2013").ToList();
return snacks;
```

Or

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 03, 25);
var snacks = Snacks.Where(s => s.ActivityDate == date).ToList();
return snacks;
```

Comment: @John - where applies a filter.  It will take the `Snacks` collection and only return results where the predicate is true (ActivityDate is equal to 25/03/2013)

Answer (score 2):

here is statment for that

```
var result = list.Where(item => item.Date.Equals(yourdatevalue))
```